# Union of Permutations

Tags: combinatorics

Having $k$ different permutations, $\pi_{1},\dots,\pi_{k}$, we write a permutation in one-line nonation, namely $\pi=i_1i_2{\dots}i_n$, that is, $\pi(1)=i_1,\pi(2)=i_2,\dots\pi(n)=i_n$. The union of permutations is defined as follows:

$$\forall i{\in}[n],\ U_i=\{{\pi}_1(i),{\pi}_2(i),\dots,{\pi}_k(i)\}$$

Note that in $U_i$ there may be repetitions, so $|U_i|{\leq}k$, let $s=\sum_i^n|U_i|$, so I want to ask, what is the minimum $s$ for any $k$ permutations?

Also, if $k=n$, and the $n$ different permutations are $\pi_{1}=123{\dots}n$,$\pi_{2}=(n)12{\dots}(n-1)$,$\pi_3=(n-1)(n)1\dots(n-2),\dots$; then we get maximal $s=n^2$.

My problem is about the minimum $s$ for any $k$ permutation. Intuitively, the more the different permutations share common parts, the less $s$ will be, so if we let $k=i!$, then for permutations in the form $\pi=\pi^{*}(i+1)(i+2){\dots}n$ where $\pi^{*}$ is any permutation of $1,2,\dots,i$, namely the $k$ different permutations differ only on the first $i$ eliments, then $s$ may be minimum, and $s=i^2-i+n$.

But this is a simple intuition; does any one know what is the exact answer to this question? This sounds like a very easy problem, but it is troubling me.

Comment: I proposed an edit to clarify; please see if that's what you meant.